# can we register a user to telegram from web using telegram API auth.signUp

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

Can we register a user to telegram using telegram API - `auth.signUp` from web instead of mobile (android or iOS) ?
I am using `telethon` client library of python.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can register a new user to telegram by `telethon`

```
client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)
assert client.connect()
if not client.is_user_authorized():
    client.send_code_request(phone_number)
    me = client.sign_in(phone_number, input('Enter code: '))
```

read [document](http://telethon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extra/basic/creating-a-client.html#creating-a-client) for more detail

Comment: i asked about `sign_up` .

Comment: `auth.signUp‍` :Registers a validated phone number in the system.... and  The code above registers the number and sends the confirmation code

Comment: Sorry i do not understand. please explain more.